# how to trouble shoot "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a PHP mod/addon/plugin for an opensource script. My plugin used to work but after an update of the open source script it doesn't work anymore and I get this error:

> Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Strangely I only get the error when I try to save but the script does pull content from the database so I am not sure why if the connection to the database is established for reading it would fail on writing.

The line that produces the error is:

```
$results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

How can I troubleshoot this?

Thanks

Comment: It seems your mysql connection not created. Have test your connection?

Comment: " I only get the error when I try to save but the script does pull content from the database" that would be an issue with the permissions set for that particular user. a user can have select but not insert rights

Comment: Please check permission for user you are using to connect database connection.

Comment: Just a heads up - mysql_ functions are deprecated, so would be good to start replacing them with mysqli_ or PDO variants.